# Python run external lib class directly from command line

Tags: python

So imagine i have an external lib called printer with one file that looks like this.

```
# in file ExternalLibPrinter.py
def main():
   print("hello external lib")
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now i've installed this via pip.

What I would like to do is run that main function. If this was a python file that in my directory i would simply run

```
python3 ExternalLibPrinter.py
```

but I cant find such a file. I've also tried

```
python3 printer/ExternalLibPrinter.py
```

This can't find that file either. So is this not possible?

Comment: Please share acually lib name and what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to call the main function :

```py
import printer.ExternalLibPrinter as printer
printer.main()
```

If however the `main()` function was in the module's `__init__.py`, you would call it this way :

```py
import printer
printer.main()
```

If you want to know where are the library's files stored, do this :

```sh
$ python3
>>> import printer
>>> printer
<module 'printer' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/printer/__init__.py'>
```

In this example it shows where `printer` is installed on my computer, but that may be different with yours.

If the library is a single file, it will be called `printer.py`. If is is in multiple files, there will be a directory named `printer` which will contain :
`__init__.py` — File that is used when you write `import printer`
and for each submodule there will be a file `submodulename.py` that is used when you write `import printer.submodulename`.